# Critique: how to show validation message in a tabular form

Tags: critique, tables

So basically my page looks as follows:

[image]

It has a table (table 1)

What I have to do is show a validation message which contains the following information in a tabular form (table 2) :

> Source Bank|Destination Bank|Amount|Created By|Status|Group 1|Group 2
>
> xyz     | abc            | 1202 | ttt      | Fali |   ✔   |   X

The table to be shown in the validation (table 2) can contain any number of rows and should be shown above the original table (table 1) and its design should be consistent with the design of the original table (table 1).

Please give me some suggestions regarding how and where to show the table 2

Comment: You seem to have answered your question yourself "should be shown above the original table(table1)" & "design should be consistent with the design of the original table". What more are you looking for? You need to be a bit more specific

Comment: When an error occurs you want to add a column on top of it with the Error message? Why not just ad an additional column with the errormessage to the aditional column?